# How to view an attachment to a Google Calendar without logging in to Google?

Tags: google-calendar

I created a work calendar for all classes we teach or have taught at facilities.
Under description you have an option to attach. I would like people to view the flyers for more description of what the class is about. I can click on this attachment and view because I created the calendar, but when one of our employees click on the attachment flyer it asks for a Google sign in. I embedded this calendar by sharing & making it public for all to see. What if you don't have a Google account how can they view this?

Answer (score 1):

The employees will need permission to view the file. Giving them permission to view the calendar doesn't automatically give them permission to view the file you linked to.

Assuming the file is stored in Google Drive you will need to change the permission in Drive for this file to either 'Public on the web' or 'Anyone with the link'.